# listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem() returns null to the NEW item added in the listbox

Tags: wpf

This is my first post here so I hope you could help me with my problem regarding WPF.

I have a listbox that is bind with an ObservableCollection:

```
    public ObservableCollection<DeviceSetting> DeviceSettings
                {
                    get { return _deviceSettings; }
                    set { _deviceSettings = value; }
                }

   <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource IPItemTemplate}" Name="listBoxAddresses" SelectionMode="Extended" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TestSetting.DeviceSettings, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}" />
```

The situation here is, I would like to know if a new item has been added to the list so what I did was create a CollectionChanged event:

```
TestSetting.DeviceSettings.CollectionChanged += mListBox_CollectionChanged;  

private void mListBox_CollectionChanged(object sender,NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < TestSetting.DeviceSettings.Count; i++){

       ListBoxItem myListBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)(listBoxAddresses.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listBoxAddresses.Items[i]));


        if (!TestSetting.DeviceSettings[i].IsNetwork && DeviceDiscovery.IsSelected)
                  myListBoxItem.IsEnabled = false;

        else if (TestSetting.DeviceSettings[i].IsNetwork && !DeviceDiscovery.IsSelected)
                  myListBoxItem.IsEnabled = false;
        else
                  myListBoxItem.IsEnabled = true;

     }
 }
```

But a problem occurs at this statement:

```
ListBoxItem myListBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)(listBoxAddresses.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listBoxAddresses.Items[i]));
```

Everytime I added a new item, the statement above always returns null so the new item that was added was not checked if would be enabled or not. Is there a way for this statement to return the correct ListBoxItem that I need?

Comment: Why just not use bindings inside ItemTemplate (with a help of some Converter)? You\`re checking properies anyway, you only do this manually right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're handling the underlying collections `CollectionChanged` event. Just because the collection was changed does not mean that the item has been rendered and the `UIElement` is ready.

Register for the `ItemsGenerator.StatusChanged` event which should guarantee that the `UIElement` is ready.

Comment: Thank for the reply. So does this mean I should register for ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged instead of CollectionChanged event? And where would I place my logic for item enabling?

Comment: Anyway thanks so much I have figured it myself. Instead of CollectionChanged event, ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged is enough and moved my logic to this event. Thanks Aaron

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the `ItemsGenerator.StatusChanged` event in Windows Phone, but it worked with `listBoxAddresses.LayoutUpdated`

I also had to make sure `myListBoxItem` was different from null.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're loading the control and trying to access...

```
ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(object here)
```

I was able to work around the issue by doing it in my ListBox.Loaded event.  For example

```
SourceColumnListBox.Loaded += SourceColumnListBox_Loaded;
```

Then inside the SourceColumnListBox_Loaded handler, things worked fine.